# create multiple dataframe from one dividing column numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of 105 columns. I want to create 10 data frames from that where 1st 5 columns will be present in all data frames and each data frame will contain 15 columns in total (10 new columns, from big data frames). That means I want to fix 5 columns, divide the rest column numbers with 10 and add the resultant column numbers with those fixed 5 columns (by index). For example:

```
bigdf.columns= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
smalldf1.columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
smalldf2.columns=[0,1,2,3,4,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

Any help? Not sure if my explanation made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple loop like this and `locals()` to create variables dynamically:

```
for i, c in enumerate(range(5, len(df.columns), 10), 1):
    dfsmall = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :5], df.iloc[:, c:c+10]], axis='columns')
    locals()[f'dfsmall{i}'] = dfsmall
```

*(Numbers 5 and 10 are hard coded for easier highlighting)*

```
>>> dfsmall1
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

>>> dfsmall2
   A  B  C  D  E  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks `@Corralien`. Now if I want to do some operation in each small data frames, how could I do this.